# Performing additions within multiple columns of different rows in a SQL Server table based on the text in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to figure a query which performs some additions and subtractions of data in different rows and different columns  based on the text/data in some other column in the same table.

Problem can be clearly addressed with the following example

Consider, I have table named `Outright` with four `fields/columns` with several records as follows

```
Product    Term    Bid   Offer
------------------------------
A          Aug14   P      Q
A/B        Aug14   R      S
B          Aug14   X      Y
B          Sep14   ab     xy
B/C        Sep14   pq     rs
C          Sep14   wx     yz
```

When I run the query it should look for the Products that is separated by `/`  in the above case there are two products of that type `A/B and B/C`and then it should look for individual products based the those that are separated by `/` like we have a product `A/B` which is separated by a `/`, so it should look for `product A and B` with same term as `A/B` and perform some operations and return the data as follows

```
Product    Term    Bid   Offer
------------------------------
A          Aug14   a      b
B          Aug14   c      d
B          Sep14   ab     cd
C          Sep14   abc    cde
```

in the above results

```
a=R+Y  b=S+X  
c=Q-S  d=P-R
```

where `P,Q,R,S,X,Y` are `Bid` and `Offer` values from the table `Outright`

similar calculations are applied for all other data too like for `B/C Sep14..` and many other

Example

Table Outright

```
A   Oct14  -175 -75
B   Oct14   125  215
A/B Oct14   NULL -150
```

Result should be

```
A Oct14  NULL          -150+125=-25
B Oct14  -75-(-150)=75  NULL
```

The above values are calculated using the equations mentioned earlier
May I know a better way to solve it in SQL Server 2012?

Comment: I would recommend normalizing your table first.

Comment: I think it is already

Comment: You think that a column with two values in it, A/B, is normalized? Ouch.

Comment: it is just a single value in my case and it has nothing to with individual values A and B

Comment: your results don't match the data shown, where is D=P-R coming from? Why are you adding some and subtracting others? It looks like you are putting multiple products, multiple bids and multiple offers into a single row which is far from normalized. From your second table, where did offers b, d, cd, cde come out of the first table when no offers used those values.  You should probably clean up your example before asking whether anything can be done because there is no rhyme or reason to your example.

Comment: @Kevin If you have read my question properly, it would be clear that, ad,cd,abc,cde are assumptions and they are similarly calculated as I did for a,b,c,d (please loot at the mathematical equations in the question so you can find what a,b,c,d are ab,cd,abc,cde are similarly calculated for B/C and B,C )

Comment: Lets take row C Sep14 wx yz, how does it get d in the offer output when in no place in the row does P or R exist for C. (you said d=P-R) Make a real example or show the sql that is generating this, because this doesn't show any equations that work at face value.

Answer (score 0):

Ok lets create some test data:

```
DECLARE @Outright TABLE
(
    Product VARCHAR(10),
    Term VARCHAR(10),
    Bid VARCHAR(10),
    Offer VARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO @Outright
VALUES
('A',  'Aug14','P','Q'),
('A/B','Aug14','R','S'),
('B',  'Aug14','X','Y');
```

Making a cte to try to figure out the logic posted above and match the single product line to the multiproduct line

```
;WITH t AS
(
    SELECT 
        a.*, 
        d.DRN, 
        d.Bid dBid, 
        d.Product dProduct, 
        d.Offer dOffer,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a.Product) RN
    FROM @Outright a
    OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY d.Product) DRN
        FROM @Outright d
        WHERE d.Product LIKE (a.Product + '/%')
            OR d.Product LIKE ('%/' + a.Product)
    ) d
    WHERE d.Product IS NOT NULL
)
```

Now we try to implement the + - rules as stated above (bids to offers, offers to bids, etc)

```
SELECT
    *,
    CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN FE1_1 + '+' + FE1_2 ELSE FE1_1 + '-' + FE1_2 END Col1,
    CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN FE2_1 + '+' + FE2_2 ELSE FE2_1 + '-' + FE2_2 END Col2
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN Product END) Prod1, 
        MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN Term END) Term1,
        MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN dBid END) FE1_1,
        MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN Offer END) FE1_2,
        MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN dOffer END) FE2_1,
        MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN Bid END) FE2_2,
        1 RN
    FROM t
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN Product END) Prod2, 
        MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN Term END) Term2,
        MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN Offer END) FE3_1,
        MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN dOffer END) FE3_2,
        MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN Bid END) FE4_1,
        MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN dBid END) FE4_2,
        2 RN
    FROM t
) d
```

Here is the output, with some extra columns to show the data being pulled

```
Prod1   Term1   FE1_1   FE1_2   FE2_1   FE2_2   RN  Col1    Col2
A   Aug14   R   Y   S   X   1   R+Y S+X
B   Aug14   Q   S   P   R   2   Q-S P-R
```

Comment: My best guess at what you are trying to attempt in sql.  probably need to also put the term in the where clause as well to handle each individual date, I'll leave that as an exercise for you.

Comment: also you will need to partition by term in that row_number, and group by term for each union :)

Comment: I was just using those P,Q,R and so on as just symbols for my actual values. I have edited the question with an real world example. Please see

Comment: outside of the couple of fixes I stated above, (and that I was outputing text rather than doing calcs) does the logic work for you?